# Which is the order SOLR filters are executed?

Tags: solr

Is there a specific order these filter are executed? I tried to move the filters around and I haven't got clear results.

```
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're executed in the order you've defined them.

Moving them around might not change anything, as it'll depend on how the tokens are transformed by that specific filter. The tokenizer is the only exception as that will be executed before any regular filters, while any `charFilters` will be executed before the tokenizer (i.e. charFilter -> Tokenizer -> filters).

You can use the `Analysis` section under the Solr admin page to see how each filter processes tokens in sequence and what the input and result is for each step of the chain.

You'll also have to reload your configuration (usually done by reloading the core or collection) after changing it.

Comment: Im afraid it’s not fully correct. If we are talking only about <filter> than yes, the order. However tokenizer and charFilter and filter as a groups executed in order, no matter what’s the order would be

Comment: ok so the order is all the tokenizer, then all the charFilter and then the filter. then each group (internally) depending on the order. is that correct?

Comment: First charfilters, then the tokenizer, then the other filters. There's only one tokenizer - if you need to process your content further, there's filters to use for that (such as the worddelimiterfilter).

Comment: @Mysterion Thanks, I've clarified that part now. The question was about the filters, but I can see how my phrasing could be misunderstood.